# TypeScript better way to define big models

Tags: typescript

So I am working on an application which has some large models used sometimes, an example is seen below:

```
import CapcodeModel from "./CapcodeModel";

export default class MeldingModel {
  hash: string;
  id: number;
  tijd: string;
  melding: string;
  adres: {
    straat: string;
    plaats: string;
    postcode: string;
    longitude: string;
    latitude: string;
  };
  discipline: string;
  disciplineId: number;
  disciplineVolledig: string;
  regioNaam: string;
  regioStream: string;
  cruciaal: boolean;
  proRail: boolean;
  capcodes: CapcodeModel[];

  constructor(
    {
      hash,
      id,
      tijd,
      melding,
      adres,
      discipline,
      disciplineId,
      disciplineVolledig,
      regioNaam,
      regioStream,
      cruciaal,
      proRail,
      capcodes
    }: MeldingModel = {
      hash: "",
      id: 0,
      tijd: "",
      melding: "",
      adres: {
        straat: "",
        plaats: "",
        postcode: "",
        longitude: "",
        latitude: ""
      },
      discipline: "",
      disciplineId: 0,
      disciplineVolledig: "",
      regioNaam: "",
      regioStream: "",
      cruciaal: false,
      proRail: false,
      capcodes: []
    }
  ) {
    this.hash = hash;
    this.id = id;
    this.tijd = tijd;
    this.melding = melding;
    this.adres = adres;
    this.discipline = discipline;
    this.disciplineId = disciplineId;
    this.disciplineVolledig = disciplineVolledig;
    this.regioNaam = regioNaam;
    this.regioStream = regioStream;
    this.cruciaal = cruciaal;
    this.proRail = proRail;
    this.capcodes = capcodes;
  }
}
```

It has default values just so I can assign it as:

```
const _melding = new MeldingModel();
```

aswell as

```
const _melding = new MeldingModel({ /* all props assigned here */ });
```

Now, this big model looks absolutely hideous and hard to maintain in my opinion, is there a way to clean this up, while still being able to use it's default values?

Comment: Extract `adres`, `disciplin` maybe other properties

Comment: @AlekseyL. how would I apply default values to them too..?

Comment: Same as now....

Comment: @AlekseyL. You mean separate classes for those objects, right?

Comment: Not necessary classes, could be just plain objects (`MeldingModel` as well)

Answer (score 1):

I would implement as a simple object with default values:

```
export default class MeldingModel {
  hash = "";
  id = 0;
  tijd = "";
  melding = "";
  adres: {
    straat: "";
    plaats: "";
    postcode: "";
    longitude: "";
    latitude: "";
  };
  discipline = "";
  disciplineId = 0;
  disciplineVolledig = "";
  regioNaam = "";
  regioStream = "";
  cruciaal = false;
  proRail = false;
  capcodes: CapcodeModel[] = [];
}
```

Then you can do this as before:

```
const _melding = new MeldingModel();
```

For your second constructor approach you can use:

```
const _melding: MeldingModel = { /* all props assigned here */ };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can break it further to have the properties of `address` and `disciple` defined as interfaces respectively

```
  hash = "";
  id = 0;
  tijd = "";
  melding = "";
  adres: Address
  discipline: Discipline;
  regioNaam = "";
  regioStream = "";
  cruciaal = false;
  proRail = false;
  capcodes: CapcodeModel[] = [];
}
```

Have your object initiated this way. It automatically gets all the properties in the class. You can also define your default values if you want

```
const _melding = new MeldingModel();
```